# Manhattan distance between a point and straight segment specified by its end points

Tags: geometry

is there a simple way to express the Manhattan distance between a point and a segment specified by its two endpoints? The segment is limited so it's not always possibile to use the minimum distance between a point and a straight line.
I am working in R^N, not in R^2 or R^3, so i need a more general formula.

I need this for an algorithm so the solution could use "if" conditions if a close form doesn't exist.

Thank You

Wentu

Comment: My biggest issue is the N-dimensionality. There's a formula online to get the Manhattan distance between a point and an infinite line. With some more conditions i guess i could treat the finite segment. But when N dimensions come in, i can't figure out how to generalize it properly, because you can't write a line as a single equation, you need hyperplanes intersecting. I guess a line expressed parametrically should be used but then i can't see how to treat the given formula. The site is this: http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/maths/manhattan/html/manhattan.html

Comment: For those who are interested, this is the solution in R^N but for euclidean distance: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just do $\Bbb R^2$, but the extension should be clear.  Let the point be $(a,b)$ and the segment from $(c,d)$ to $(e,f)$.  Parameterize the segment as $(c+t(e-c),d+t(f-d))$.  The distance is a linear function of $t$, so can have no local maximum or minimum.  You just need to check the endpoints and the points where it is no longer differentiable.  So check $(c,d),(e,f)$ and the values of $t$ where $c+t(e-c)=a$ or $d+t(f-d)=b$

Comment: Thank you very much, i think i can generalize it to N dimensions easily now; even if it's not the answer i was expecting, it shows a great way of thinking. Am I wrong or with this method the time increases linearly with N since i have to check N+2 cases? Is there a way I can make it O(log(N)) instead, with some sort of dicotomy search?

Comment: Worth noting: If the slope of the line is $1$ or $-1$, the distance function can be constant on an interval of positive length, in which case there are infinitely many closest points. (Note that the question didn’t require finding closest points, only minimum distance, so your answer is still correct.) Let the point be $(2,4)$ and the segment from $(0,0)$ to $(6,6)$. The endpoints are not closest, and your answer checks the distance for two non-endpoints, $(2,2)$ and $(4,4)$. These are closest points, but so are $(3,3),(\pi,\pi)$, and every other point between $(2,2)$ and $(4,4)$.

Comment: @JohannesWentu:  I don't think so. I think you can do a binary search, but setup will be $O(n)$.  If $a\lt ce$ or $a \gt c,e$ there is no reversal from that dimension.  I think you will have to go through all the dimensions to add up the coefficients of $t$ and to determine whether there is a reversal.  Then you can do binary search, but you have already done $O(n)$